# JOIN results in too many rows

Tags: sql, join

I would be super happy if I get help for this problem. Thank you in advance.

Table #1: `station_temporar_con_station` has 5984 rows, and 7 columns as seen in the screenshot:

```
ID_stations, latitude, longitude, connection_coord_city_type_coordinates_text, type_of_stations, ID_city
```

[SQL_station_temporar_con_station](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggJus.png)

Table #2: `air_quality_temporar` has 11946 rows and 13 columns as seen in this screenshot:

[table air_quality_temporar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xAP3.png)

Now I should have a table with all the 11946 rows from `air_quality_temporar` supplemented with the column `connection_coord_city_type` from `station_temporar_con_station`.

What I've tried so far:

Solution #1:

```
SELECT 
    ID_measurement, ID_stations, 
    station_temporar_con_station.latitude, 
    station_temporar_con_station.longitude,
    station_temporar_con_station.connection_coord_city_type, 
    station_temporar_con_station.coordinates_text, 
    type_of_stations, ID_city
FROM 
    station_temporar_con_station
JOIN 
    air_quality_temporar ON station_temporar_con_station.coordinates_text = air_quality_temporar.coordinates_text;
```

But this JOIN results in 14'377 rows instead of 11'946 rows.

Solution #2:

```
SELECT 
    reference, pm25, PM10, latitude, longitude,
    (SELECT connection_coord_city_type 
     FROM station_temporar_con_station),
    conc_pm25, conc_pm10, year, pm10_type, pm25_type, date_compiled 
FROM 
    air_quality_temporar;
```

But only the first value from `connection_cord_city_type` is filled in, because the DB does not know what it should assign where.

Does anyone have any input or a solution?

Comment: You have duplicate rows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Exactly there are duplicate rows.

Because of this I would like to make this column connection_cord_city_type. This column would be unique.

Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: First you need to determine which table has duplicate `coordinates_text` (it might be both but I assume `station_temporar_con_station`).  Then you need to decide what criteria you want to use when selecting which station you want where there are duplicates.  Then apply that criteria.  There is no magic SQL than can "know" which row you want so you have to factor it into your query.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. 
The solution was to find the duplicates in the previous tables. These were created mainly by empty fields. After I eliminated the duplicates, the join worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid duplicate connections and `join` only unique data. I added two `latitude` and `longitude` fields to the join below.

I also used the left join and the air_quality_temporar table in put left table To recover 11946 rows.

```
SELECT ID_measurement, ID_stations, 
 station_temporar_con_station.latitude, 
 station_temporar_con_station.longitude,
 station_temporar_con_station.connection_coord_city_type, 
 station_temporar_con_station.coordinates_text, type_of_stations, ID_city
FROM air_quality_temporar
LEFT JOIN station_temporar_con_station
ON air_quality_temporar.coordinates_text = station_temporar_con_station.coordinates_text
AND air_quality_temporar.latitude = station_temporar_con_station.latitude AND
air_quality_temporar.longitude = station_temporar_con_station.longitude
```

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicates in your tables.  The one of interest is `station_temporar_con_station`.

To find the duplicates, use:

```
SELECT coordinates_text, MIN(connection_coord_city_type), MAX(connection_coord_city_type)
FROM station_temporar_con_station
GROUP BY coordinates_text;
```

Then you need to figure out what to do.  I would suggest fixing the data.

If you just want to get *any* matching row in the query, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT aqt.*, stcs.*
FROM air_quality_temporar aqt LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT stcs.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY coordinates_text ORDER BY coordinates_text) as seqnum
      FROM station_temporar_con_station
     ) stcs 
     ON stcs.coordinates_text = aqt.coordinates_text AND
        stcs.seqnum = 1;
```

Note that this returns an *arbitrary* row when there are duplicates.  I also replaced the `JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`.  The duplicate rows might be hiding the fact that some rows have no matches.